# how to re-run openRTSP programmatically

Tags: live555

How to re-run openRTSP (Live555) programme programmatically?

usual scenario example:

- run openRTSP for any right stream
- stop openRTSP in the middle of processing
- re-run openRTSP with the new right stream

note: the above mentioned must work only programmatically.